# Handling error for separate register and login services

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple authentication system.
I have two separate files for login and register functions.
I will provide the register function below.

```
const User = require('../models/User')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

const register = async (data) => {
    //hash the password 
    var hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(data.password, 10)
     //create the user
    const user = new User({
        username: data.username,
        email: data.email,
        password: hashedPassword
    });
    try {
        const createdUser = await user.save()
        return createdUser
      } catch (err) {
        return err
    }
}
module.exports = register
```

As you can see register runs asynchronously and returns the created user if everything goes correct otherwise returns an error.

Below is the route which uses this service.

```
const router = require("express").Router()
const User = require("../../models/User")
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
var bcrypt = require("bcryptjs")
const register = require('../../services/register')
const login = require('../../services/login')
const { registerValidation,loginValidation } = require('../../services/validator')


router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {

  //validate data before creating user
  const { error } = registerValidation(req.body)
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message)

   //check if user  exisits
   const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
   if (user) return res.status(400).send({status:400,message: "User already exists!"})

  //register the user
  try {
    const registerResult = await register(req.body)
    return res.send(registerResult)
  } catch(err) {
    return res.status(500).send({status:500,message:"Something went wrong."})
  }
});
module.exports = router
```

But the problem is await always returns resolve that's why we use catch.
In the `Register` service everything is fine it will catch the error and it will return it.
But in the router :

```
try {
    const registerResult = await register(req.body)
    return res.send(registerResult)
  } catch(err) {
    return res.status(500).send({status:500,message:"Something went wrong."})
  }
```

`registerResult`  variable catches everything it doesn't matter if it's `error` or `result from resolve` 
Aslo I am repeating `try` and `catch` in both modules.
I want to catch any error that happens during creating user and send a custom error.
**Is there any better patter  to get the error from Register service?**

Comment: In your register service inside the catch block throw `throw new Error(err)` instead of return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return any things (result or error) the caller supposes it's a valid result.
In the register function you are returning both result & error!
You should return the result but throw the error.

```
try {
    const createdUser = await user.save()
    return createdUser
  } catch (err) {
    throw err
}
```

Or even you can do this:

```
const register = async (data) => {
    //hash the password 
    var hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(data.password, 10)
    //create the user
    const user = new User({
        username: data.username,
        email: data.email,
        password: hashedPassword
    });
    return await user.save();
}
```